# Joomla website breaks when include custom code file

Tags: php, joomla, include, joomla2.5

I've posted a problem I have (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263141/joomla-website-not-working-after-moving-to-new-server) with my website. And noticed the problem only happens when I insert some code I have and need on the site. In the code I have a Class and use it around my files.

Things worked for about 2 months and now don't work. I haven't change anything on the code and have used it in previous templates in the past.

I guess I'm not including it correctly the way Joomla likes it but, can't understand what's going on.

Here's the class which is a simple DB connection and link id:

```
// Class db: Connects to database and returns linkid.
class MY_DB{

  var $sqlhost; 
  var $sqluser;
  var $sqlpass;
  var $sqldb;
  var $err;
  var $status;
  var $num_rows;
  var $result;
  var $linkid;
  var $query;
  var $rows     = Array();
  var $last_insert_id;

  function MY_DB( $query="", $db="" ){

    if( $db != "" ){ $this->sqldb = $db; }
    else{ $this->sqldb = "dbase"; }

    $this->sqlhost  = "localhost";
    $this->sqluser  = "root";
    $this->sqlpass  = "pass";


    $this->query    = $query;

    if( $this->query == "" ){
      $this->__Connect__();
    }
    else{
      $this->__Connect__();
      $this->__TalkToDB__();
    }




  }// end constructor Session


///////////////////////////////////////// 
  function __Connect__(){
      //connect to mysql
      $this->linkid = mysql_connect( $this->sqlhost, $this->sqluser, $this->sqlpass );

      if( $this->linkid ){
        $this->result = mysql_select_db( $this->sqldb, $this->linkid );
      }
      else
        $this->err = "Could not connect to MySQL server";
    }// end Connect function
/////////////////////////////////////////    
  function __TalkToDb__(){

      $this->result = mysql_query( $this->query, $this->linkid );

      if( !$this->result ){
        echo ( "Query: '" . $this->query . "', failed with error message: -- " . mysql_error() . " --" );
      }     
  }// end TalkToDb function
//////////////////////////////////////////

  function __CountRows__(){
      $this->num_rows = mysql_num_rows( $this->result );

      return $this->num_rows;

  }

//////////////////////////////////////////  
  function __LastInsertedId__()
  {
    return mysql_insert_id( $this->linkid );
  }


}// end class definition

?>
```

Here's another file I include:

```
<?php
// select random activity
$num_acts_display = 2;

$query = "select id from activity where enabled='Y'";
$all_ids  = array();

$act_id   = new MY_DB( $query ); 


while( $all = mysql_fetch_array($act_id->result,MYSQL_BOTH) ){

    $all_ids[] = $all['id'];

}

// shuffle it
shuffle( $all_ids );
// re-shuffle it
shuffle( $all_ids );

?>
<div class="random-figureo">
    <ul>  
<?

for( $i = 0; $i < $num_acts_display; $i++ ){

  $query = "select * from activity where id=".$all_ids[$i];
  $act = new MY_DB( $query ); 
  $a = mysql_fetch_array($act->result,MYSQL_BOTH)


?>

  <li>
    <div class="random_img">
     <a href="<?=$this->baseurl?>/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=537&Itemid=194&page=thumbnails&amp;act_id=<?=$a['id']?>">
     <?
      $portada = get_portada($a['id'], "", true);

      if( $portada == "none" ){
     ?>
      <div style="background:#666; width:100px; height:65px; padding:0px; margin:0px;"></div>
     <?}
        else{// "templates/" . $this->template .
     ?> 
       <img src="<?= "templates/" . $this->template . substr( $a['directory'],1,strlen($a['directory']) ) . "/" . $portada ?>" width="100" height="65" alt="<?=$a['act_name']?>" />
     <?}?>
     </a>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="random_title">
      <a href="<?=$this->baseurl?>/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=537&Itemid=194&page=thumbnails&amp;act_id=<?=$a['id']?>"><?=$a['act_name']?></a>
    </div>
  </li>   
<?
}
?>      
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's how I include it:

```
include( "templates/" . $this->template . "/includes/db.class" );

include( "templates/" . $this->template . "/random-figureo.php" );
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using J!2.5.8 with PHP version: 5.3

Comment: What is the error message you are receiving when it doesn't work?

Comment: Since you said you moved to new server I would double check to make sure your hostname for MySQL `$this->sqlhost = "localhost";` is indeed `localhost`. I recall my site breaking because the hostname had changed from localhost to a domain name such as db.myhost.com for example.

Comment: If I remove the includes, things work perfectly.

When included then joomla's modules don't load and most of page looks blank for except the code I've included.

Comment: If I include my code, only my code shows and not extensions.

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't have stuck to Joomla coding standards instead of creating a new database class and so on. would make life so much easier and might solve your problem.

Comment: I had this code for about 3 years, back then I wasn't using joomla. So, now I started using joomla and needed that code on the new site.

Comment: If you are saying it used to work and now it works, something must have changed.
Did anything on your server get updated? Do you have error reporting on development and what is the error report tellign you? What is in your apache error log?
Dd you change any lines of code e.g.put a close tag or an open tag somewhere?
Did you update Joomla i.e. was it working on 2.5.7 and now not on 2.5.8? 
Also, without knowing where you added this it's really hard to know.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the problem:

> Blockquote This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

So, I changed my files' mysql extension to mysqli and now everything works...

I'm still using php 5.3 and looks like it doesn't like the mysql_fetch_array...

Thanks all for your time. Hope this helps someone else in the future. It took me three days of frustration, time, and my site being offline.

Comment: If you have solved this issue, award your answer the green tick to mark this page as resolved, por favor.  You have a few abandoned questions on this site; please endeavor to progress every question toward a system-recognized resolution.  If you have any new Joomla-based questions, please engage the Joomla Stack Exchange community.